# How to create a cygwin executable

Tags: linux, bash, drupal, cygwin, symlink

I was trying to follow the instructions here to get drush installed on cygwin:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1432756#comment-11184267

However, running "drush" from my drupal project's folder did nothing (it didn't tell me `-bash: this_command_I_made_up: command not found` as it does for a command that doesn't exist).

Eventually I tried to run the symlink command like this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/src/drush/drush.bat /usr/bin/drush.bat
```

instead of this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/src/drush/drush.bat /usr/bin/drush
```

In other words, I added the .bat suffix to the filename path (`drush.bat`) instead of leaving it as plain old `drush`. Now I get results as I expect when running drush commands from my drupal project folders, but I have to type in `drush.bat` instead of `drush` when running drush commands.

I was just wondering if anyone could shed some light on the situation as to why the plain old `drush` symlink without the `.bat` suffix doesn't work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to make the src/drush/drush.bat executable.  If the symlink you make has a .bat extension (or .exe, etc.), it will automatically be executable in cygwin.

For files without extensions, the file must be marked executable.

For symlinks without extensions, the source (src/drush/drush.bat) must be marked executable.

To mark a *file* executable, use the command `chmod +x src/drush/drush.bat`.